# Galois theory occurence in (very) Applied Mathematics

Tags: galois-theory, applications

Can Galois theory be used in (very) Applied Mathematics; e.g. Population Dynamics, Biostatistics or $\langle$some Mathematics course that is (almost) opposite of Abstract Algebra$\rangle$. I know that Galois theory is used in other Algebra subjects (like Cryptography), but I'm looking for those really unexpected connections of Galois theory with subjects seemingly unrelated with it.

Comment: Galois theory is used in cryptography (e.g. Frobenius automorphisms of finite fields), based on elliptic curves.

Comment: @Watson I know that Galois theory is used in other Algebra subjects (like Cryptography), but I'm looking for those really unexpected connections of Galois theory with subjects seemingly inrelated with it.

Comment: For statistics, look into experimental design. It's the only place I've seen abstract algebra come up in my statistical courses.

Comment: This is not an application, but Galois theory is related to geometry / topology via the theory of covering maps — the deck transformation group corresponds to the Galois group, for instance.

Comment: What do you consider to be Galois theory? For example, many of the pleasant properties of complex conjugation can be recast as special cases of the theory

Comment: I consider Galois theory as looking at subfields, separable field extensions, automorphism groups, Galois groups and bijective maps from field- to field extension. The applications are, as many may know, that some polynomials with a degree bigger than 4 don't have a solution formula and that you can't construct certain angles or n-sections of an angle with only a ruler and compass.

Comment: About ten years ago telecommunication engineers used Galois extensions of number fields to construct nice radio signal constellations for multiantenna transmission/reception. I'm a bit hesitant to call it an application of Galois theory. It was more about orders of division algebras over quadratic imaginary number fields. The proofs of the properties of the constructed signal sets did take advantage of some Galois theory. A former graduate student and a close friend of mine solved the problem of finding the densest signal sets (w.r.t. a certain figure of merit) using class field theory.